# Heroku Hobby Dyno Confusion

Tags: heroku, dyno

The hobby level dyno does not sleep, but the cost is prorated to the second so you only pay when the dyno is running. But how would it not be running if it doesn't sleep?

I'm just trying to boost my personal website into a more professional one and trying to figure out my best hosting options.

Answer (score 2):

> But how would it not be running if it doesn't sleep?

It would only be *not* running if you scaled it down -- either with `heroku ps scale web=0` or from the Heroku Dashboard.